# Creating lucene index for oracle db - performance

Tags: oracle, lucene, hibernate-search

After exchanging my pc with a pc of *identical* hardware I reinstalled all software. A spring-boot app uses hibernate-search to create a lucene index on startup. The database (schema, indices,...) and data itself are identical to the old setup. Everything works fine (the app etc.) except now the creation of the index takes a lot longer. Before 75 documents have been created per second but now only 7. I compared the database parameters and they are the same. To make sure there is no hardware problem I used a disk performance tool to compare the pc's (the new one is a *little* faster).

What could be the cause of that huge decrease in performance and how could I solve it?

Comment: Do you still have access to the old PC? Can you try to build and run the app in a completely new workspace, see if you get the same performance as before? If you don't, there may be something in your workspace that alters the setup. Overridden loggers that are much less verbose in the old workspace, for example. If you get the same performance, it may be something with how your OS is configured, or the version of an OS component, of the database, ... You could try to monitor the mass indexing through VisualVM in both environments, see if something stands out.

Comment: Also, if you're currently running the mass indexing through you IDE, try outside of the IDE. IDE bugs might explain the difference, if you're using different versions of the same IDE.

Comment: Yes, I still have access to the old pc. I tried it on the new pc from the IDE (9 docs/sec) and command line (10-11 docs/sec) and the same on the old pc (56 docs/sec) where again the command line was a bit faster than from the IDE. I am pretty sure the bottleneck is somehow the database. But I am not a db admin and don't know where to look at. The version and parameters are the same (oracle xe 11g). Will try to do more tests next week.

Comment: Oh, I though you had already checked that, since you said the database was identical to the old setup. Yes, it's likely that a database configured differently would result in this kind of performance hit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to update this post. The reason was too many eager fetching sets. When creating the index all tables are then left outer joined. A huge query was the result. Now changed all to lazy fetching and it runs just fine .

:$